# updating user in RMQ with specific role with rabbitmq python literary

Tags: python, api, rabbitmq, rabbitmqadmin

I want to update the user in rmq with only permission of reading queue with python rabbitmq_admin package .
What should I use in the fields of

```
api.create_user_permission('username', '/', configure='', write='', read='queue')
api.create_user_permission('user', '/', configure='$^', write='$^', read='queue')
api.create_user_permission('user', '/', configure='', write='', read='queue')
```

I have tried all the above mentioned thing but the user gets all the access, I want the user to have only :`read='queue'`

I want the permission as follows:

```
Virtual host    Configure regexp    Write regexp    Read regexp
/                                                          queue
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the issue with the package it self . i just replaced the part of the package in which it was hard coding the default as '.*'.

Open the package in site package folder (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages) in you computer and open the api.py file in edit mode.
After that just replace the part of create_user_permission function from

data = {
            'configure': configure or ' .* ',
            'write': write or ' .* ',
            'read': read or ' .* ',
        }

TO

data = {
            'configure': configure or '',
            'write': write or '',
            'read': read or '',
        }

this will solve the problem